# Why document.referrer doesn't get #

Tags: javascript, referrer, document.write

Is it standard that when using `document.referrer`it doesn't bring out the parameters after # ? I am using the code as below just to check a script I'm building:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write (document.referrer);
</script>
```

This is ideal as I don't want to send any details after url to a site I'm linking to

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is normal and expected. The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20090303/html.html#ID-95229140) of `document.referrer` says:

> Returns the URI [IETF RFC 2396] of the page that linked to this page. The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark).

And the [URI RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) says:

> 4.1. Fragment Identifier
>
> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the  identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional   reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the   retrieval action has been successfully completed.  As such, it is not part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

So `document.referrer` contains a URI, but the part after `#` is not part of the URI, and is therefore not included.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is standard. Browsers do not send the `#` or anything after it to any server. This is true for the URL that is sent to a server when you click, and also for the referrer.

The Wikipedia page on [fragment identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) describes this behavior; see the Basics section.

That's for URLs that the browser sends on its own, e.g. when you click a link. If you have JavaScript code on a page that uses `XMLHttpRequest`, then that JavaScript code can send *anything* to a server. The actual URL sent by the browser for the `XMLHttpRequest` will still omit any fragment identifier in the URL, but the JavaScript code can escape and package up that information and send it as part of a query parameter or as `POST` data (both of which are sent to the server). This is how Google Analytics can send the fragment identifier, as noted in Barmar's comment below.

Comment: lovely. I have a wierd issue I don't know if anyone can help. When using this script on my site I can see the referrer (everything before # - as per standard as you say); however in google analytics it shows me know referrer? My site is http and same domain?

Comment: @Manny GA uses Javascript that runs on the webpage itself, so it can use `document.location` to get the full URL.

Comment: thanks @barmar the issue is that its not get any source (ie sitename.com) other than user data, should i consider this an issue with my site even though document.referrer works fine?

Comment: @Manny I don't understand your problem, or how it's related to the fragment part of the URL. What does "it shows me know referrer" mean? Did you mean "no referrer"?

Comment: yes i did above was a typo sorry (couldn't edit). I'm happy that anything after # won't be sent to the outgoing site, my curiosity is if the document.referrer on my site is fetching the correct url why is google showing up as no referrer? I am manually clicking on link and giving google enough time to process (currently set my href to another page on my site to test this)